# How to use android SDK reference

Tags: android

Been learning Android for two months now,Have a little java knowledge but I don't seen to know, how to use the android SDK  reference at all..For example,If I want to make sliding tabs,under the views,All the info I get, just a series of "Inherited methods,public methods etc." Is there any particular convention I am supposed to follow when using the SDK reference.

Comment: you need to master Java, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/194812/list-of-freely-available-programming-books , thinking in Java is a good choice if you ask me.

Comment: Oh I failed to mention,I have a little java knowledge (OO programming)

Comment: if you don't get what the instructions says to you, you need to keep studying Java, there is all you need to know in this docs, you still have to grasp some more concepts about Java and practicing more.

Comment: *sighs* Maybe I'll just start java again even if there isnt much time....But how much more java is needed and which book can you recommend?

Comment: *Thinking in Java*, just follow the link above, you can reach a good level of practice with in a short period of time, but you have to do some exercises and explain to yourself all the things that you can't understand in the first place and do not assume that you know everything after just reading a chapter the first time.

Comment: I mean I understand most of the code in the android books,but The Android SDK reference just never gives me what Im searching for just a long list of irrelevant stuffs

Comment: it's not irrelevant, it's what you are supposed to use, for this reason you have to keep studying, because you still don't master Java completely, you can also find many groups about Android if this matters to you groups.google.com/group/android-developers

Comment: Yh,I found out that I was only familiar with the syntax,Now That I know what those private,public,implements actually mean I found it relatively easier,Thank you very Much,Mark

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Knowing java is a good ground-base for Android development. If you are currently learning Android development, I suggest you get your hands on a book (that suits your needs) and have a look at the newBoston [series](http://thenewboston.org/list.php?cat=6).

I hope this helps.